# REMOVEFILTERS not doing what I expected in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hi I have the following data and am trying to return a distinctcount of the number of Teams irrespective of what teams are filtered to, but taking into account the filters applied to Client.

[image: Team Client Data]

i'm using the following DAX

```
Total Team Count = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Sheet1[Team]),REMOVEFILTERS(Sheet1[Team]))
```

I've filtered my data to **Client** = aa and bb so am expecting **Total Team Count** = 4 (a, b, c & g)

this works fine when I filter to **Team** = a or b However c & d return a **Total Team Count** = 3
it seems filtering to c returns a count of a, b & c whilst d returns a, b, g. So it seems to be returning a distinctcount of the **Teams** with a common **Client** to the **Team** filtered to.

What am I doing wrong?
How do I get it to return **Total Team Count** = 4 irrespective of the **Team** filter?

Comment: Is your DAX defining a calculated column?

Comment: @AlexisOlson No, I've set it up as a Measure.

Comment: Is there any other filter context from your visual or other filters/slicers?

Comment: No, the only Filters I have are on Team and Client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a case of [auto-exist](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-dax-auto-exist/) run amok. Please read the linked article.

In your case, when you filter down to Team `c`, the only remaining Client is `aa`, which means despite having Client `bb` selected too, the Client column has been indirectly filtered out by Team `c` even though you later try to remove that filter from Team in your measure.

As mentioned in the article, the solution is to build a star schema that breaks out dimensions into their own tables.

Comment: Nightmare! The project I'm working on is much bigger than the example, so converting it to star schema will be quite a job. But thanks for pointing me in the direction of what's going on.

Comment: The bigger the project, the more important it is to have good structure. It saves a ton of headache in the long run.

Comment: I've Star Schema'd the data from the question and it works! It seems there's no simple workaround using just the one datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using remove filters use allexcept.
You can use the following dax formula:

```
Total Team Count = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Sheet1'[Team]), 
    ALLEXCEPT('Sheet1', 'Sheet1'[Team], 'Sheet1'[Client])
)
```

Comment: That returns a total Team Count = 1. 
I've tried Total Team Count = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Sheet1[Team]),ALLEXCEPT(Sheet1, Sheet1[Client])) However that has the same issue as my original problem.