# How to use ALL() in a measure of a line chart that ignores filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I thought I knew how to use the ALL() function but it doesn't seem to be working with my filter.

my tables looks something like this:

```
Serial#   Result  SMU
A         1       0
B         1       0
C         0       0
A         2       500
B         2       500
A         1       1000
C         1       500
B         0       500
C         2       500
```

I then have two measures:

```
AllAvg = CALCULATE(AVERAGE([Result]), ALL([Serial#]))
Avg = AVERAGE([Result])
```

I then want to plot both of these measures on a line chart with SMU as my axis.  I want to be able to select a Serial# and basically compare its Average to the population's Average.  I would expect when I select a Serial# on my filter that the 'AllAvg' value would not change; however, it does. Why would this be the case? What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I think this is the same issue as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65815491

Comment: I think you are right. I had to create copy of my table, then intermediary tables to join the original and new table by each column I wanted to use a slicer. I then changed some visualization interactions and I was able to make it work. Crazy.

Comment: When you had a single table, the values changed because in the visualization you added a filter (SMU-axis) that was not corrected by the first measure. I suppose it would have been easier to use ALL(TableName) instead of ALL([Serial#]) if you wanted to keep using a single table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a copy of my table.  Then created a bridge table full of just distinct SMUs.
I left my AllAvg measure and changed the other measure to work for the new table. So Avg = Average(table2[Result]).  I then added a slicer for table2[Serial#].  Created a line chart with my AllAvg and Avg measures, and when I used my slicer for table2[Serial#], my AllAvg line stayed completly stagnant just how I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

AllAvg = CALCULATE(AVERAGE([Result]), ALL())

Answer (score 0):

Also Try this.

AllAvg = CALCULATE(AVERAGE([Result]), removefilters()
)