# DAX REMOVEFILTERS not working as expected

Tags: powerbi, dax

I know this is a commonly asked question, but after hours of research, I still can't figure out why this isn't working.

I'm using a general ledger as a fact table in my Power BI data model. I have a slicer pane which allows the user to filter by fund, department, and transaction type (Actual or Budget). However, for certain visuals I want to ignore the transaction type selected in the slicer.

I created two measures: `[Actuals Total]` and `[Budget Total]`. They're pretty much the same, but here is the DAX for one of them:

`Budget Total = CALCULATE(SUM(GL[Amount]),REMOVEFILTERS(GL[Transaction Type]),GL[Transaction Type]="Budget")`

But as you can see below, it appears the filter on transaction type still applies.
[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: First, REMOVEFILTERS in your measure is redundant, because expression GL[Transaction Type] = "Budget" already includes ALL. Second, it does not work as expected because you are using a flat table instead of a star schema and it causes auto-exist to fail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65815491/removefilters-not-doing-what-i-expected-in-power-bi

Comment: I created a dimension table for Transaction Type and updated the DAX, but it still isn't working. I would think I'd need the REMOVEFILTERS part, because I need to override the slicer selection of Actual. But either way, it returns blank for [Budget Total].

Comment: I just tested my suggestion, and it works fine. There must be something else that causes the issue. Could you please post the updated DAX? Also, which table/field are you using for the slicer?

Comment: REMOVEFILTERS is not needed here because it's already present in your DAX - it's just hidden under "syntax sugar": https://exceleratorbi.com.au/simple-filters-and-syntax-sugar-in-dax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create a proper star schema from your GL table. It should look something like this:

[image]

Then, write 3 DAX measures (the first one for convenience):

```
GL Amount = SUM(GL[Amount])

Actual Total = CALCULATE( [GL Amount], Trx[Trx Type] = "Actual")

Budget Total = CALCULATE( [GL Amount], Trx[Trx Type] = "Budget")
```

Notice that REMOVEFILTERS is not necessary because syntax sugar hides an implicit ALL in these measures, which in full version look like this:

```
Actual Total =
CALCULATE (
    [GL Amount],
    FILTER ( ALL ( Trx[Trx Type] ), Trx[Trx Type] = "Actual" )
)
```

ALL here is identical to REMOVEFILTERS.

Also notice that you must use Transaction type **from the dimension**, not from the GL table.

Finally, make sure that the slicer is based on the transaction type from the dimension, not from the GL table.

Results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That worked! The problem was that I was still using transaction type from the GL table, not the dimension table. Also, good advice on the implicit ALL bit. Thank you!